# PHP; How to securely store password protected login as cookie?

Tags: php, security, cookies

This is my `PHP` code.

```
<?php
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";
$session = $_COOKIE['session'];
$private_key = "!$//%$$//%$&=§$!&%&=§$!&%";

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password) {
        setcookie("username", $username, time()+(10*365*24*60*60));
        setcookie("session", md5($password.$private_key), time()+(10*365*24*60*60));
        echo "You are are logged in!";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong login!";
    }
}


if(isset($_COOKIE['session'])) {
    if($_COOKIE['username'] == $username && $_COOKIE['session'] == md5($password.$private_key)) {
        echo "You are are logged in!";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong login!";
}
}
?>


<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="login">
</form>
```

What this code does: When you login with correct data, a cookie will set with username and hashed password. Username isn't secret and can be stored in clear text. Password is combined with a cryptic string before hashed to prevent somebody could guess the password. He won't have success without knowing the `$private_key`.

When re-visiting the page, you are already logged in because of the cookie.

Of course my script isn't perfect but: Is it the right way?

Without the correct login data you cannot login. A hacker will also not be able to find out the password because it's combined with a cryptic string.

But a hacker could read the cookie data in some way and will be able to login only using the cookie data by manipulate the cookie data in his browser. How can I prevent it?

Comment: no it's not the right way. do not send the password back to user, encrypted or not. Do not save it as cookie, encrypted or not. Do not save it in db as plain text, use password_hash and password_verify.

Comment: To keep the user logged in store an authorization token that gets refreshed (newly created) on each visit.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38141/if-hashing-is-one-way-why-can-we-decrypt-md5-hashes

Comment: @Jeff But what if a hacker has this authorization token? Won't he be able to use this in his own browser?

Comment: yes, he would - once. But he wouldn't get the user's password nor your private_key. Next time the real user is online he's out (unless he changed the password.. which he shouldn't be able to do without knowing the old one plus email-verification).

Comment: @Jeff Hey, Jeff, thanks for your answer. But I still don't understand. Let me try to explain: A user logins with username and password. If both are right, an authorization token (only that, nothing else) get stored as cookie and in the database. Next time user visits the page my server checks if the authorization token stored as cookie is the same as the authorization token stored in the database. That means everybody who has this authorization token will be able to login by manipulating its own browsers cookie without the need to know the password or the private_key. Aren't I'm right?

Comment: @Jeff `Next time the real user is online he's out`: Why that? How can server know who's the real user without login again with username and password?

Comment: @Jeff `that gets refreshed (newly created) on each visit`: Without login with username and password again? This will also work for the hacker, won't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177435/discussion-between-david-and-jeff).

Comment: If the refreshToken doesn't match the real user would be forced to login again, yes. The real user can pass that, the hacker can't. Additionally you could store the browser's signature, maybe the ip-address to limit 'auto-login'. All of that can be faked of course. But if it's wrong only once, then the authToken would expire, user has to login.

Comment: The code above is vulnerable to 1. session fixation, 2. wrong use of cryptography (you want an authenticated hash, but concatenating the key is not the right way, take a look at hmac), 3. insecure hash algorithm (md5) 4. potential offline attacks against the secret key 5. a hard-coded secret. This is pretty much the guinea pig of session management vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to implement a "remember me on this computer" feature (a.k.a. persistent authentication on top of sessions), you're about to enter a veritable rabbit hole of complexity. I suggest reading [this dedicated guide](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence) to the topic.

To summarize the strategy: **Do not store passwords in a cookie (hashed or otherwise).** Instead, you're going to use randomly generated tokens. Specifically, a [split token](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/02/split-tokens-token-based-authentication-protocols-without-side-channels).

#### Long-Term Authentication ("Remember Me Across Sessions") Cookies

```
<?php
class Authentication
{
    /** @var PDO $db */
    private $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }

    public function createLongTermToken(int $userId = 0): string
    {
        // Build the components
        $tokenLeft = base64_encode(random_bytes(15));
        $tokenRight = base64_encode(random_bytes(33));
        $tokenRightHashed = hash('sha256', $tokenRight);

        // Insert into the database
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO auth_tokens (user_id, selector, hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
        );
        $stmt->execute([$userId, $tokenLeft, $tokenRightHashed]);
        return $tokenLeft . ':' . $tokenRight;
    }

    public function loginWithPersistentCookie(string $cookieValue): int
    {
        // Input validation
        if (strpos(':', $cookieValue) === false) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid authentication token');
        }
        list($tokenLeft, $tokenRight) = explode(':', $cookieValue);
        if (strlen($tokenLeft) !== 20) || strlen($tokenRight) !== 44) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid authentication token');
        }
        $tokenRightHashed = hash('sha256', $tokenRight);

        // Fetch from database
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM auth_tokens WHERE selector = ?");
        $stmt->execute([$tokenLeft]);
        // Now our token data is stored in $row:
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Delete token after being retrieved
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM auth_tokens WHERE selector = ?");
        $stmt->execute([$tokenLeft]);

        // Verify the right hand side, hashed, matches the stored value:
        if (!hash_equals($row['hash'], $tokenRightHashed)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid authentication token');
        }
        return $row['user_id'];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Post-authentication, before headers are sent:
$cookieValue = $auth->createLongTermToken($userId);
setcookie(
    'long_term_auth',
    $cookieValue,
    time() + (86400 * 30), // 30 days
    '',
    '',
    TRUE, // Only send cookie over HTTPS, never unencrypted HTTP
    TRUE  // Don't expose the cookie to JavaScript
);
```

On page load:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['long_term_auth'])) {
    try {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $auth->loginWithPersistentCookie($_COOKIE['long_term_auth']);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // Security error! Handle appropriately (i.e. log the incident).
    }
}
```

The above code snippets assume that `$auth` is an instance of the example `Authentication` class. It also assumes a basic table structure for `auth_tokens` (`user_id` points to the users table, `selector` and `hash` are VARCHAR or TEXT fields, with a unique constraint on `selector`).

#### Why is this code secure?

- It separates long-term authentication cookies from the users' passwords.
- Tokens are only allowed to be used once.
- It uses `random_bytes()` to generate secure tokens.
- It uses SHA256 (instead of MD5) to store the larger piece of the auth. token.
- It uses `hash_equals()` to compare hashes.
- It only sends the long-term authentication cookies over HTTPS.
- It uses the built-in session management features of PHP.

#### Why is the question's code insecure?

- It uses MD5, which is not a secure hash function.
- It uses `==` instead of `hash_equals()` to compare hashes. See also: [magic hashes](https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/magic-hashes/).

---

Furthermore, you'll want to use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for the actual user authentication steps. This just describes a secure implementation of the "remember me" checkbox convenience feature.

For better security, you'll probably want to use something like [`password_exposed`](https://github.com/DivineOmega/password_exposed) and/or [zxcvbn](https://github.com/bjeavons/zxcvbn-php) to prevent weak/compromised passwords from being used.

Your users will want to use a **password manager** such as KeePassXC, 1Password, or LastPass to generate/store their passwords for your website so they don't end up using weak passwords like `admin`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I would recommend to also create a token (or add the information to the right hand token) with a small browser fingerprint (hashed and NOT labeled as finger print of course). If browser addons or maleware steal a cookie, it will add a (small) layer of extra security.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But how to clean tokens when they are expired?

Comment: Delete the row from the database.

Comment: Yeah. But the deleting process should be automatic. How to automate this delete process is PHP?

Comment: Deleting a row from a database table is never automatic. If you want a cleanup process, queue up a cron job that runs `DELETE FROM table WHERE (invalidation rules go here)`. Or delete after use.